# How does the Mac SE/30 send video to the analog board?

Tags: apple-macintosh

I can't seem to find where the video signals leave the digital board of my `Mac SE/30` and travel to the analog board that is connected to the monitor.

I even searched for pinouts online but I guess my searching skills are failing me.

As far as cables are concerned, I can identify the power cables, the SCSI cable, the floppy cable and the audio cable.

My assumption is that it's buried in one of the power cable connections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The video signals are on the 14-pin Mini-Fit Jr. connection that goes between the logic board and the analog board. It's labeled J12 on the logic board. You can see it labeled in this image:

[image: Apple Board (Click to Enlarge)]

You can find the schematics at [museum.dyne.org](http://museum.dyne.org/gallery/apple/stuff/mac/andreas.kann/schemat.html).

Comment: Great first post!